# Date of Birth JavaScript Function - Getting rid of Pop ups

Tags: javascript, function, popup, popupwindow, date

I've been using the following Date of Birth JavaScript Function for years on my site and all of a sudden it now brings up a pop-up which I don't require with that value in? I only require the value to display inside the p tag.

```
<p>I'm xxxxx. I have over 
<script>
var dob='20050613';
var year=Number(dob.substr(0,4));
var month=Number(dob.substr(4,2))-1;
var day=Number(dob.substr(6,2));
var today=new Date();
var age=today.getFullYear()-year;
if(today.getMonth()<month || (today.getMonth()==month && today.getDate()<day))
alert(age);
document.write(''+age+'');  
</script>
years' experience xxxx.</p>
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove `alert(age);`

Comment: Awesome, thanks @KooiInc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
<p>I'm xxxxx. I have over 
<script>
var dob='20050613';
var year=Number(dob.substr(0,4));
var month=Number(dob.substr(4,2))-1;
var day=Number(dob.substr(6,2));
var today=new Date();
var age=today.getFullYear()-year;
if(today.getMonth()<month || (today.getMonth()==month && today.getDate()<day))
//alert(age);
document.write(age);  
//return(age);
</script>
years' experience xxxx.</p>
```

The main change is removal of an `alert()` function.